# Security risk of $update_access_free = true in Drupal

Tags: security, drupal

What kind of potential security risk it raises if I left `$update_access_free = TRUE` in Drupal on a production environment? In that case, [everyone can run *update.php*](http://drupal.org/upgrade/running-update-php). Assuming there are no updates available, what can an attacker do?

Comment: DDOS attack? (123456790)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If left enabled, an attacker could run old updates, which in a good scenario would only bog down your site's performance, but in a worst-case scenario could result in data loss or data corruption.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even allow access as it is unnecessary.

Someone could constantly access and run this page, using system resources.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is a way to easily update your site, you should add a cron job with a Drush command to update the site at mid night. Now, from time to time developers release module fixes or upgrade that might brake something on your site. Hopefully in Drupal 7 the update can be done using the site interface and I am sure there might be some sort of console module to keep multiple sites update.

Comment: Not really. I was curious what security risk it raises if I accidentally left `$update_access_free` enabled. But it's a good point that it's a real problem when automatic site update is configured.